# Transform SQL SERVER table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

i have this table 
[table with evaluators and evaluatees.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUKbt.png)

Every row of the table above is a relationship between two people(First row:person a evaluates person b, Second row person a evaluates person c and so on).

I want to trasform this table into looking like this
[Wanted Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WrHI.png)

So Each row will correspond one evaluator and each column will be people being evaluated by him. (Because some evaluators have less people to evaluate than others the remaining columns for someone who doesnt have that many evaluatees will be NULL.

Many thanks hope you can help me out

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have SQL Server tag so, i would use `row_number()` function with conditional aggregation :

```
select evalutor, 
       max(case when seq = 1 then evalutee end) as evalutee1,
       max(case when seq = 2 then evalutee end) as evalutee2, 
       max(case when seq = 3 then evalutee end) as evalutee3 
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by evalutor order by evalutee) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
group by evalutor;
```